# Is there a way to trigger an immediate push replication for specific artifacts and not the whole folder in JFrog Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, artifactory-query-lang

I referred to the REST API documentation [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-Pull/PushReplication). It works for folders. However, it is not working for individual artifacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not REST API method for triggering replication for a specific artifacts.
You can use the [event-based push replication](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Replication#RepositoryReplication-PushReplication) instead or on top of the scheduled replication - artifact replication will occur in nearly in real-time since each create, copy, move or delete of an artifact is immediately propagated to the far end.

If you wish to limit the artifacts being replicated to a given path you can:

1. Configure a "Path Prefix" - Only artifacts that located in path that matches the subpath within the remote repository will be replicated
2. Create a custom user plugin with a [replication](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-Replication) execution point - plugin can have logic to decide whether to replicate or skip based on the artifacts path

Comment: Yes but an event based push replication will also replicate the whole folder. I want only specific artifacts to get replicated. Is there any way to do that?